Self-concordant barrier for the epigraph of $f(x,y) = x^p y^{1-p}$?
The problem
Assume $p > 1$. Consider the function
$$f(x,y) = x^p y^{1-p}, \qquad x,y > 0.$$
Note that
$$
f'' = p(p-1)x^{p-2}y^{-1-p}
\begin{bmatrix}
y \\ & x
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -1 \\
-1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
y \\ & x
\end{bmatrix},
$$
which is positive semidefinite. Thus,
the following epigraph is convex:
$$Q = \{ (x,y,s) \; : \; s > f(x,y), \qquad x,y > 0 \}.$$
What's a self-concordant barrier for $Q$?
Variations and discussion
More generally, I'm interested in the following function:
$$
f(x,y) = \|x\|_2^p y^{1-p},
$$
and the corresponding epigraph.

If you delete variable $y$ (i.e. set $y=1$), a well-known self-concordant barrier is:
$$F(x,s) = -\log(s^{2 \over p} - \|x\|_2^2) - 2\log s .$$
I've written a quick and dirty numerical program that computes the relevant third order tensor norm (to see if it's self-concordant). I don't trust this program too much, it might have bugs, but it seems to tell me that the "obvious" modification below, is not self-concordant:
$$
F(x,y,s) = -\log(s^{2 \over p} - \|x\|_2^2y^{{2 \over p}-2}) - 2\log s - 2\log y.
$$

An alternative would be to "model" the problem differently by introducing slack variables, etc..., but the epigraph of $f$ has so far eluded my attempts at this approach.

I always ask my questions too fast and then immediately find the answer.
Let $\alpha = 1/p \in (0,1]$. The set $Q$ can be characterized instead by
$$
x < s^{\alpha}y^{1-\alpha}.
$$
This is a convex cone, the barrier for this has been worked out in a thesis by Chares. Chares gives the following barrier:
$$
F(x,y,s) = -\log(s^{2\alpha}y^{2 - 2\alpha} - x^2) - (1-\alpha)\log(s)-\alpha \log (y).
$$
The parameter of the barrier is $3$. Several related barriers are conjectured, e.g. if $x$ is a vector.
